# How to order table based on dropdown value in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having this table of users and I want to be able to filter them. I have a textbox to order by name and that works but my dropdown list to order them by name or email doesn't.

This is my dropdownlist:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 mb-2 lg-6">    
    <select class="form-control" name="userfilter" id="userfilter">
        <option class="genrekeuze" value="id">Sort By</option>
        <option class="genrekeuze" {{ request()->name }} value="name">Name (asc)</option>
        <option class="genrekeuze" {{ request()->name }} value="name">Name (desc)</option>
        <option class="genrekeuze" {{ request()->email }} value="email">email (asc)</option>
        <option class="genrekeuze" {{ request()->email }} value="email">email (desc)</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is my controller: I want to make $vallist to have the value of the dropdown (default must be ID on pageload)

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $vallist = "id";
    //vraag input van zoekbalk en option list
    $zoeknaam = '%' . $request->input('name') . '%';
    $vallist = $request->input('userfilter');
    //users uit database halen, paginate en where functie voor filteren
    $users = User::where('name', 'like', $zoeknaam)
        ->orderBy($vallist)
        ->paginate(15);
    $result = compact('users');
    Json::dump($result);

    //naar view met data
    return view('admin.users.users', $result);
}
```

The error I'm getting is "can't order by "" ". I'm getting this error when loading the page. I know that I have 2X name and email in my dropdown but that's just temporary.

Comment: you need to add your `select` in a form tag and submit it to receive it in your controller

Comment: Thanks for the comment but the problem is that my page won't load when I have $vallist as my orderby parameter.

Comment: you need to check if the request of `userfilter` is not empty after changing it

Comment: try this one `$vallist = $request->input('userfilter')?  $request->input('userfilter') : 'id'`

Comment: What is `Json::dump($result);` doing?

Comment: @Rwd It's a helper function to see if I'm having the right data. You can view the Json by putting "?json" right after the URL. It doesn't do anything to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#retrieving-input), you can pass a second parameter to `$request->input()` which will be the default if the actually value isn't in the request:

```
$vallist = $request->input('userfilter', 'id');
```

So your controller would look something like:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    //users uit database halen, paginate en where functie voor filteren
    $users = User::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('name') . '%')
        ->orderBy($request->input('userfilter', 'id'))
        ->paginate(15);
    $result = compact('users');
    Json::dump($result);

    //naar view met data
    return view('admin.users.users', $result);
}
```